# Uneditable text box time date hour

Tags: javascript, html, date, time, hour

How can i show a date and time format of

```
21 October 2020 Wednesday 10:15am
```

in a form of JS and HTML and put them in an uneditable text box?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out `momentjs` `https://momentjs.com/`

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // October 21st 2020, 3:24:01 am
```

or

```
moment().format('LLLL'); // "Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:33 AM"
```